# php facebook photos likes and comments

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, photos

I setup a gallery on my site using some code I found online, doing this through php and blueimp gallery, it all works and I set it up mostly the way I want it to but now I want to try to add a like button and comments from the facebook photos to the gallery.  I'm very new to js and my php is very rusty so bear with me.  Again I got the code off another site and have some understanding of both php and js but reading through the code a bit i'm a bit lost as to how to add it to the existing code setup. I added the likes and comments request but I don't know how to call for it in the js, any help?

```
$json_link = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{$album_id}/photos?
fields=source,images,name,likes,comments&access_token={$access_token}";
$json = file_get_contents($json_link);

$obj = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);

$photo_count = count($obj['data']);

for($x=0; $x<$photo_count; $x++){

// $source = isset($obj['data'][$x]['source']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['source'] 
: "";
$source = isset($obj['data'][$x]['images'][0]['source']) ? $obj['data'][$x]
['images'][0]['source'] : ""; //hd image
$name = isset($obj['data'][$x]['name']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['name'] : "";

echo "<a href='{$source}' data-gallery>";
    echo "<div class='photo-thumb' style='background: url({$source}) 50% 50% 
no-repeat;'>";

    echo "</div>";
echo "</a>";
```